# How do you access variables (attributes) which are inside a classes method?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I access the attribute/variable a inside the method yes form the body of the program outside of the class? What I have below gives me an error.

```
class test:
    def yes(self):
        a=5


g=test()
print(g.yes.a)
```

Comment: It is a local variable, you cannot. Make it an instance variable by assigning it to `self.a`

Comment: @dentalfloss, you may consider accepting an answer that helped you: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work cheers

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly access the variable, even if 'g' is an object of 'test', and yes() is it' method, 'a' is still a local variable for yes(). You haven't initialized it for the entire class. So your object cannot access it. You need to return its value from the function. This should work

```
class test:
    def yes(self):
        a=5
        return a

g=test()
print(g.yes())
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would want to access it, but here's another way to do so:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.for_returns = defaultdict()

    def yes(self):
        a=7
        self.for_returns['a'] = 7

    def return_all(self):
        return self.for_returns

x = test()
x.yes()
x.return_all()
```

> defaultdict(None, {'a': 7})

Answer (score 0):

Variables defined within a function have local scope, and can't be accessed from outside the function.

If you want to access a variable from inside a function, `return` it from the function:

```
class test:
    def yes(self):
        a = 5
        return a


g = test()
print(g.yes())
```

However, I suspect you may want to look at setting the variable as an instance variable:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = None

    def yes(self):
        self.a = 5
        # Do some other things here...

g = test()
g.yes()
print(g.a)
```

Finally, if you're using external code, and are interested in this for the sake of debugging, then the [python debugger (pdb)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) will let you inspect variables within a function.